# Let X be a non empty set equipped with the cofinite topology T. Is (X,T) compact? Is it connected?

Tags: general-topology

I have something, but I don't really know if they are strong enough (or correct) answers.

So; For proving it is compact.

In the cofinite topology, A is open if and only if X\A is finite.
Let C be any open covering of X and A be contained in C.
For every x in X\A there exists Ax in C since C is a covering.
Now, AU{Ax:x is in X\A} is a finite subcover since X\A is finite.
Hence we can say that the topology is compact.

And, I am not really sure about proving it is connected, just realised what I had written down was complete rubbish.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For an open cover $\mathcal {C}$ of $X$

- Take an element $A$ in $\mathcal{C}$ how many elements does $X/A$ have?
- How many open sets do you need to cover $X/A$?

For connectedness

- Can two distinct non-empty open sets of a cofinite topology ever be disjoint?

Comment: so what would be my first step?

Comment: your first step would be to think about the hints given above...